# How to set common Bar Button Item on Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I want to set the common Bar Button Item on the right of the Navigation Bar, it should be display on all screens managed by Navigation Controller and it calls the same action.

Just for example, in Master Detail Application template, there is "addButton" on the right of the Navigation Bar, I want to display it on DetailViewController as well (it won't be work because action is missing though).

I have created a subclass of UINavigationController, in which I can change something like Navigation Bar color, but I can't set Bar Button Items. I can set Bar Button Items in each screen's ViewController so that I have to duplicate action for each screen.

Also I've tried to create a subclass of UINavigationBar, but I don't know if I can add Bar Button Item on it.

How to set common Bar Button Item on Navigation Bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you subclass the UIViewController to have your preset barbuttonitems and then use the the subclass everywhere?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Because there are not only UIViewControllers but also UITableViewControllers. Then should I create subclass of both UIViewController and UITableViewController? I don't know if this is a good practice for the common Bar Button Item.

Comment: This seems to be the easier solution. You just have to create two custom classes right?

Comment: If you don't want to subclass, then you could use a category on UIViewController (extension in Swift) that would add a method to create the button. You would still need to add code in each controller to call this method, but it would only be a single line.

Comment: @rakeshbs yes, in this time I just have create two custom classes. So I don't mind creating them.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks. Using category sounds good to me. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use category to approach it. Let's say `UIViewController+NavigationBar` category

1.Create a category

2.Add a method, `-(void)setNavigationBarItem` method (in this case) in `.h` file.

3.implement the method in `.m` file to deal with the set Bar Button Items stuff.

```
- (void)setNavigationBarItem
{
  UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(something)];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchItem;
}
```

4.In which viewController you want the NavigationBarItem, import the category header and call `[self setNavigationBarItem]` method.

Comment: Hmm I don't know why down vote, either. It seems an example implementation using category that mention in the above comment. I haven't try this code yet though.

Answer (score 6):

Another easy way to do instead of creating an extension

implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in root view controller

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    let backBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "HINIBO", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("menuButtonAction:"))
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backBarButton
}
```